# In Redux, do I have to import store to access data in this case?

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

This is my container:

```
this.setObj(obj)
let activeButton = 0;
anotherObj.options.forEach((option, index) => {
  if (option.id === defaultId) {
    activeButton = index;
    this.setButton(index); //setButton is a common function, so I cannot pass obj as argument to it
  }
});

setObj(obj) {
  this.props.setObj(obj);  //calls an action creator
}

setButton() {
  let {obj} = this.props;
}
```

my action:

```
setObj = (obj) => ({
    type: 'SET',
    obj
})
```

my reducer:

```
switch(action.type) {
  case 'SET':
    return {...state, id: action.obj}
}
```

and I have `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

Now I have find one problem.
if I call `setObj()` in my container, and then call `setButton()` after that, the `obj` is not updated.
According to Dan, because it is asynchronous.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/291

so in this case, should I import store to access the latest `obj`?

```
import store from './store'

    setButton() {
      const state = store.getState()
      let { obj } = state;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the async nature of javacript you should indeed try to call the getId function from the `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if(nextProps.id !== this.props.id) 
    this.getId(nextProps)
}
getId(props) {
  console.log(props.id)
}
```

If you are using redux thunk you can also make use of `.then` callback on setId like

```
setId(id) {
  this.props.setId(id).then(() => {this.getId()});  //calls an action creator
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. the above code is a simplified code. In my real code, I have to call `getId()` after `setId()`. is it a good idea to use `store.getState()`?

Comment: in this [link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/291), Dan Abramovic said:
_So calling dispatch will update the store state immediately but your components will be updated a bit later during the same tick, together._

because store state is updated immediately, if I use getState() I assume I can get the latest data, right?

Comment: Dan is right, However Can you try the callback method

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I've changed my code to use `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: Glad it helped :)